# is optional binding is value type or reference type in swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

Today I met a situation where I was doing optional binding with array of objects as optional.

I have array of object at class level & on some function call I was doing optional binding & remove items from it. But if did optional optional biding then removed an objet from the array the original array still had that item.But if I removed from original array then item is removed.

```
extension WishlistController:WishlistActionDelegate {

    func removedFromWishList(voucher: ShopVoucher) {

        if var arrayWishlist = self.arrWishlist {
            for (index,value) in arrayWishlist.enumerated() {
                if value.id == voucher.id {
                    self.arrWishlist?.remove(at: index)
                    self.tableViewWishList.reloadData()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Optional binding has nothing to do with **value** or **reference** type.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are value types, so your `arrayWishList` and `self.arrWishlist` are two separate instances, and removing an item from one will do nothing to the other.

As an aside, this whole thing can be reduced to

```
self.arrWishlist = self.arrWishlist.filter({$0.id != voucher.id})
self.tableViewWishList.reloadData()
```

Comment: This code is not the same. Your answer removes all values with a matching id. The OP's code only removes the first value with a matching id.

Comment: That's more indicative of a bug on OP's part, if `self.arrWishList` can have *multiple* items with the same ID. Ideally, it wouldn't be an array at all; it'd be a *Set*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using code as Below to remove

This will remove First Matching Id in Array and Exit Execution

```
var myArray : [String]?

myArray = ["item0","item1","item0","item1","item0","item1","item0","item1","item0","item1","item0","item1"]

let voucherID : String = "item1"

print("MyArray : \(myArray!)")

if (myArray?.contains(voucherID))!
{
    let index : Int = (myArray?.index(of: voucherID))!
    myArray?.remove(at: index)
}

print("After Removing:\(myArray!)")
```

Console Output

[image]